# Dojo Textbox spellchecking not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, dojo

I am using DOJO **"dijit/form/TextBox"** TextBox control. Seems to be working fine in chrome as well in IE. Except in IE the spell checking is not working in the textbox.

Is there something specific that I need to handle to work in IE?

Following image is for IE

[image: IE]

Following image is for Chrome

[image]

Comment: Anyone can help..? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a browser feature. It is Chrome that provides the spell checking, not dojo.

Comment: there is nothing related to dojo or js , it's a browser's feature ,

Comment: i noticed html input spell checker is working in IE but dojo input is not.. quite tricky..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to turn-on spell checker in IE?

Manage Add-ons->Spelling Correction->English(United states) and then check "Enable spelling correction" checkbox at the bottom.

Comment: Can you try this                                           
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/editor/plugins/SpellCheck.html